# Putting ArcMap animated map into PowerPoint?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, animation, powerpoint

Goal: Put an animated map (by time) into a powerpoint presentation.

I have a map in ArcMap Desktop 10.5 that will animate by time. The points are barred owl observations by year in California.
I have the map and it will animate over time in ArcMap. I want to put this into a PowerPoint presentation. 
What is the best way to accomplish this?

I can connect my PowerPoint to my ArcGIS Online account, but my map is in ArcMap not my Online account. I am not familiar with ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Export individual map images, one for each time step, add images to powerpoint and [animate them](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/animate-a-picture-on-your-slide-23334c65-c38d-407e-9fa4-e13a994bb098).

Comment: You can publish your map to arcgis online via arcmap if that helps. Go to `file` menu and sign in, then publish it via `share as`. See [this esri help document](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/publish-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_94021BE7D875474681DAD20D05A90AF6) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with arcgis pro, then you can export your animation into a movie, and then embed it on your presentation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can embed Maps directly into Power Point (or Excel) using the Esri Maps for Office plugins. Suggest you explore the [ArcGIS for Microsoft 365](https://www.esri.com/software/maps-for-office) site and download the plugin. If they honour time enabled datasets is another question but, as suggested above, you can export a movie of your data changing with time from within ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro. I think ArcGIS Pro makes that process a little easier.

It may be time for *you* to read the Help file, and I suggest you start at the Help page "Exporting a time visualization to a video".